# The Fn keys on my HP dv6t are mapped all wrong

Tags: 11.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, udev

I've tried going through the keyboard fixing process documented with that udev README file (as described [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hotkeys/Troubleshooting)), but I get confused pretty much right off the bat. I'm using that "/lib/udev/keymap" tool to diagnose what's going on, but the output I get is weird and the instructions don't really make clear what it is that I should do.

The problem I'm having on this laptop is that the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys all (or mostly) seem to behave as if the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is pressed.  That is, the <kbd>F6</kbd> key for example is also the "Previous Song" key when used with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> meta key on the keyboard, or at least that's what it's supposed to be.  Well, for me, if I just hit "F6", key is mapped to "previoussong".  If I hit my <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, let it go, and *then* press "F6", then it comes through as <kbd>F6</kbd>.

For some of the keys, instead of that, a single keypress is reported as *two* keys: "leftmeta" with a scan code of 0xDB, and then the "Fn" key. So, when I press <kbd>F1</kbd> (which is not labeled as having an <kbd>Fn</kbd> alternate meaning), I get what looks like two separate events.

Finally, for the <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F3</kbd> keys, labeled as being for screen brightness controls, I get no key events whatsoever if I don't precede them with a press and release of the <kbd>Fn</kbd> meta key.  They do, however, show me the brightness adjustment growler message, though they don't actually seem to have any effect on the display.

What do I need to look at in order to get the keyboard to stop being so weird?

(Again, the laptop is a brand new HP dv6t "quad edition" with a US keyboard, and I'm running 11.04.)

*Edit* — I've just now started forming a theory that the keyboard might be working as designed, which would be another reason for me to recommend against these things.

Comment: Do you just want to disable the action key mode as per here?  If that's what you are after, I'll tidy up this comment as an answer.  Let me know.  http://www.jessebandersen.com/

Comment: No, what I want is for the system to respond to "F1" correctly - that is, as "F1". Same for the rest of them. I'm quite used to having them mapped to actions, in gvim for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your computer allow you to switch the fn key row from being the F1-12 keys or the media keys? I know my computer allows this, the way I can change this setting is by going into the BIOS and selecting the option from there. I'm not sure if that is what your computer is doing though.

Comment: No, the HP BIOS allows for almost no tweaking whatsoever, and certainly nothing like that.

Comment: Whoa, hold on - you were right ... there's a BIOS option to flip the sense of the "fn" meta key.  Durr.  Thanks for pointing this out; I would never have thought of it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can search for "keyboard" in the Unity Dash and click on the Keyboard icon, then on the window opened go to the Layouts Tab and there you can choose a new layout and set what keyboard model is yours. By the description I think you need to change your keyboard model, not the layout.

Comment: There is no entry for this particular laptop. I believe what I'm going to have to do is create my own keyboard mapping, but I don't know where to start doing that, especially how to deal with the weird behavior of the "fn" meta key.